# Why does my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API work as a standalone website, but fails as a subapplication of another website?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, subapplication

I've created an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. Then I deployed it to a production Windows Server 2022 as a new website running on port HTTP 15007. After some adjustments, the application started serving requests. All good!

Then, I decided to instead run the application as an HTTPS subapplication from another website that runs Wordpress (in order to use that website's SSL certificate). I created a new integrated application pool with no managed code option and used it to run my app.

But now, no request is served: when I try to access anything over HTTPS in my app, the request never finishes. No error, no nothing, just infinite waiting.

Where do you suggest that I should try to find the solution?

- Is it a permission issue? (when checking subapplication access from IIS, I get *"The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access."*, although I've give R/X permissions to the entire folder and files to my ApplicationPoolIdentity).
- Is is a routing issue?

If I switch the application pool to LocalSystem, then I can access a test txt file, but core app won't run saying 403.19 (I guess it is asking for ApplicationPoolIdentity).

Could somebody suggest a debug procedure to pinpoint the exact problem? I've been trying to do so for the last day, so I am out of ideas.

Comment: At this step it is no more programming related but purely a server administration question. 1) Learn what is reverse proxy and why you need one to manipulate URLs of your sites/apps without "run the application as an HTTPS subapplication from another website". 2) WordPress sites by default rewrite everything to its index page, so naturally requests to your ASP.NET Core Web API are affected if you don't revise any setting.

Comment: maybe you could take a look at the application event view to see if there's any error or warning, by the way, you might create a sub website under the main website, I think you might test calling the api by click the browser button in IIS manager to make sure the url is correct. And what you did looks like not so good, to use the certificate for your api project, you might use the reverse proxy.